# how to delete last comma in each line and string that come after

Tags: regex, shell

hi all I have jtl file that hold many lines that each line have multi values seperate by comma(,).
what I wish to achieve is ready jtl to html report and there for I need to erase the last parameter in each line. I found text that show me how to read each line but can't figure up how to erase the last parameter
line for example:

```
1517341677444,180922,HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,,1530008760,195,1,1,1152,0,528,11.111.11.111
```

the **,11.111.11.111** is what I wish to delete in each file and it may have different numbers.

Comment: Use `,[^,]+$` and replace with empty string. https://regex101.com/r/oThouU/1/

Comment: the expected output should by without the same line without ,11.11.11.11

Comment: I would match `(.+),.+$` and replace with `$1`

Comment: Are you doing this in a Unix shell?

Comment: If OP is using a shell command for this, it's mostly likely being processed line-by-line in the first place and won't need need multiline mode specified. Though it would be good for OP to clarify.

Comment: the opertion system is macos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On OSX (or in any other shell) you can use this `sed` to strip last part after comma:

```
sed 's/,[^,]*$//' file

1517341677444,180922,HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,,1530008760,195,1,1,1152,0,528
```

To save changes inline to file use:

```
sed -i.bak 's/,[^,]*$//' file
```

Comment: Sorry didn't check all those comments. @S.Kablar please post your answer and I will delete mine.

Comment: you make it look so easy :)